# Chirality in Lie groups and Lie algebras

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds

Is there an example of a  chiral Lie group?In particular, is it true to say that the map $g\mapsto g^{-1}$ is orientation reversing for odd dimensional Lie groups?

Moreover is there a concept of chiral Lie algebra, a finite dimesnional Lie algebra $L$ such that every automorphism of $L$ necessarily preserves the orientation?

Comment: What do you mean by a chiral Lie group? Do you mean a Lie group whose underlying smooth manifold is chiral?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan  yes, I mean so.

Comment: I ask because "chiral Lie algebra" has a totally different meaning: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiral_Lie_algebra

Comment: Also I don't know what you mean by an orientation of a Lie algebra. Do you mean a nonzero element of its top exterior power?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Orientation reversing means det<0.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I guess that the cross product on R^3 gives a chiral Lie algebra, in the sense that I defined.

Comment: I still don't know what you mean by a chiral Lie algebra. Certainly every vector space is amphichiral in the sense that there is an automorphism of that vector space reversing an orientation of it. Are you only allowing Lie algebra automorphisms? If so, this becomes inconsistent with the corresponding terminology for Lie groups.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yes  only Lie algebra automorphisms are allowed and I agree that it is inconsistent  with Lie group analogy. But I think that it can be introduced in the context of finite dimensional lie algebras, independently.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan  i guess that the matrix  Lie algebra $M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ is  another example of  a chiral lie algebra.

Comment: .....at least when $n=4k$.

Answer (score 6):

The rational cohomology $H^{\bullet}(G, \mathbb{Q})$ of a compact connected Lie group is the exterior algebra on some odd generators, the product of which lives in top cohomology. The number of generators $r$ is the rank. The map $g \mapsto g^{-1}$ acts by $-1$ on each generator, and so it acts on top cohomology by $(-1)^r$. Hence $g \mapsto g^{-1}$ reverses orientations iff $r$ is odd iff $\dim G$ is odd.

Comment: thank you for the answer. where is  a reference on this cohomology computation? May be some more explanation?  BTW, is it now clear what I meant by orientation reversing on a Lie algebra, in terms of determinant?

Comment: @Ali: it follows from a suitable classification of Hopf algebras. See, for example, Cartier's *A primer of Hopf algebras*.

Comment: This can be seen also by observing that the differential of $g\mapsto g^{-1}$ at $e\in G$ is $-id$, working in exponential coordinates.

Comment: @Mizar Thanks for this interesting point.